# How to import pygame from a folder?

Tags: python, import, pygame

I installed pygame in my project folder (the folder where the script gets executed) because I don't want the user to download the requirements or run a setup file. First I tried installing pygame in the project folder and importing it with `import pygame` and everything went as expected.
To install it in the lib folder I used the following command:

```
pip install --target=...\project-folder pygame
```

But when I tried installing pygame in a 'lib' folder, and importing it with

```
from lib import pygame
```

or

```
import lib.pygame as pygame
```

it doesn't work and it gives the following error:

```
from pygame.base import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I noticed a lot of simple games have a 'lib' folder but I don't understand how they do it.

Comment: "But when I tried installing pygame in a 'lib' folder," **exactly how** did you do this? "First I tried installing pygame in the project folder" What is "the project folder"? How did you install there?

Comment: "I installed pygame in my project because I don't want the user to download the requirements or run a setup file" I struggle to understand this. Exactly how do you intend for users to obtain, install and use your program?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 1) I installed it with `pip install --target=...\lib` pygame
2) With _project folder_ I mean the folder where the script gets executed
3) I just want them to install the folder from github and double-click on main.py, and the libraries will already be in the downloaded folder

Comment: Suppose you had written your own code and put it in the `lib` folder. How would you import that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I would import that with `from lib import code` or `import lib.code`.
By the way I edited my previous comment and my post for the other questions.

Comment: you may add your folder to `sys.path` before you import module

Comment: @furas thankkkk you very much, that's exactly what I wanted. If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add project's folder to `sys.path` before you `import` module.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("\full\path\to\project-folder")

import pygame
```

To make sure you can insert it as first element on list.
It will always get module from your folder - even if you will have `pygame` installed also in global folder.

```
sys.path.insert(0, "\full\path\to\project-folder")
```

To make it more universal you may try to get project folder using `__file__` - and it should work even if you move all code to other folder.

```
import os
import sys

BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.insert(0, BASE)

# if `pygame` is in subfolder `lib`
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE, 'lib'))
```

If you load some images/sounds/etc. then you can also use it

```
enemy_img = pygame.image.load( os.path(BASE, 'images', 'enemy.png') )
```

Comment: `sys.path.append('lib')` worked for me, I don't know if not specifying the full path could cause problems in the future but at the moment it seems fine